# PHP validation kinda works BUT

Tags: php, forms, math

So in the form I have this input

```
<input type="text" name="squareFoot" value="<?PHP if(isset($_POST['squareFoot'])) echo $squareFoot ?>"><span class="error_message"><?PHP echo " " . $squareFootError; ?></span>
```

And here's my validation (which is yes above the form)

```
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){

        $isSubmitted = true;

        $squareFoot = $_POST['squareFoot'];
        $squareFoot = filter_var($squareFoot, FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_FLOAT, FILTER_FLAG_ALLOW_FRACTION);
        $squareFoot = filter_var($squareFoot, FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_FLOAT, FILTER_FLAG_ALLOW_THOUSAND);
        $squareFoot = filter_var($squareFoot, FILTER_SANITIZE_SPECIAL_CHARS);

        if(!is_numeric($squareFoot)){
            $isValid = false;
            $squareFootError = "Please enter a numeric value";
        }

        else if(empty($squareFoot)){
            $isValid = false;
            $squareFootError = "Please enter a numeric value";
        }

        else if($squareFoot < 200){
            $isValid = false;
            $squareFootError = "Please enter a number between 200 and 500,000"; 
        }

        else if($squareFoot > 500000){
            $isValid = false;
            $squareFootError = "Please enter a number between 200 and 500,000";
        }

        else{
/// do math (code not shown)


// Format Square Footage 
            $squareFootFormat = number_format($squareFoot, 0, '', ',');

// Display to user
<p>1. Square Footage being stripped <span class="right_al"><?PHP echo $squareFootFormat; ?></span></p>
```

So I have it set up so that the user can't put in html or script, the user must put in a number that has to be between two numbers, and that number can have a comma.

I also want the user to be able to put in something like 500.5, but when testing 500.5 turns into 5,005.

Is it because of
    $squareFootFormat = number_format($squareFoot, 0, '', ',');

Or is something else wrong with it?
I kinda want to keep the number_format() in because it makes the number easier to read if it's some large number like 100,000. Can I do that?
Thanks for helping.

Comment: `$squareFoot = filter_var($squareFoot, FILTER_SANITIZE_SPECIAL_CHARS);` is going to remove any `.` where float values would be.

Comment: check this: https://3v4l.org/663OQ to understand better your code. Basically the filter_var transforms your 500.5 into 5005. The question is what do you expect to receive at the end ? 500? 501?

Comment: I was going for 500.5, but I guess I can live with rounding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your filter_var is not going to allow 500.5 as a value.

`$squareFoot = filter_var($squareFoot, FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_FLOAT, FILTER_FLAG_ALLOW_THOUSAND);`

Comment: Thanks. That worked. Any idea why W3 Schools says...
FILTER_FLAG_ALLOW_THOUSAND - Allow thousand separator (like , )
https://www.w3schools.com/php/filter_sanitize_number_float.asp

Answer (score 1):

What about only doing this:

```
<?php


$squareFoot = $_POST['squareFoot'];
$smallest = 1;
$greatest = 100000;
    if(is_numeric($squareFoot)) {
        if($squareFoot < $greatest && $squareFoot > $smallest) {
            //do what you want
            echo number_format($squareFoot, 1, '.', ',');
        }
        else {
            echo "Please enter a number between " .$smallest . " and ".$greatest;
        }
    }
    else {
        echo "Please enter a numeric value";
    }
?>
```

Looks simplier to me.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Not what I'm looking for, but it is simple.